# Is it better to use a single layer with symbol classes or multiple layers with definition queries?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, definition-query

I use symbology classes to display my data most of the time. I think I have noticed a performance hit when using symbol classes on large datasets, although it might just be in my mind.

That got me to wondering is it more efficient to 1) symbolize a single layer by categories or 2) create copies of the layer with definition queries in-place and symbolize them as a single symbol.

Setting up definition queries and setting their symbology would take time but I would do it if it gained a performance boost overall.

Also, looking at the second to last point in [Best practices for using layer definition queries...](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/01/20/best-practices-for-using-layer-definition-queries-while-creating-features/) I saw:

> **A definition query cannot be set on a system field while creating
>   features**

That would make me lean away from option 2 even if it does have better performance.

Comment: You can often improve performance by creating indexes on fields used by a query.

Comment: Best way to do this is to try it and compare draw times. Since everything has to draw on the map no matter what you do (all things being equal), I would imagine you would see a performance hit using multiple layers with each having a definition query.

Comment: You can create multiple copies of a layer and use definition queries on those layers.  And keep the main layer (without def queries) turned off, but do  your creating onto that layer.  I have this setup here and it works decent enough.

Comment: @ed.hankins yea thats what I was getting at with scenario #2. I'm leaning toward's Kirk's idea of indexing. If I understand him correctly he suggests using scenario #1 and creating an attribute index on the field I am symbolizing.

Comment: Im curious if you got #1 working.  My main point was even with def queries, you can create features on a the main (unqueried feature class)  Good luck though,  and please post your results here!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the  "Create "Index Grid Features" You can specify the size of the grid, and this way your data becomes indexed and can provide a performance boost when you have a large dataset like yours. Make sure you check this box as well:
[image]

Now, all this will do is create a grid, so you can cut the polygons and join them to each grid.

Couple of links about the index here:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-grid-index-features.htm
and
http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//003n0000001r000000

Edit: Just saw Kirk answered in the comments :)

Comment: Does the Data Driven Pages create spatial index? I thought it simply made a grid for the data driven pages to use as areas to display. And is it a spatial index or attribute index that I need in this case?

Comment: I would try Kirk's suggestion first by creating an attribute index.  You are right about it simply making a grid, but you can join the attributes to it.  It is not used solely for Data Driven Pages.  Also, there is a tool called "Add Spatial Index" so you could try that as well, but I have never used it so I can't comment on it :)